# Present ViewController with Scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a game menu with button start game:

```
@IBAction func startGame(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gameViewController") as? GameViewController {
            vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Game over code:

```
if lifes == 0 {
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainMenuViewController") as? MainMenuViewController {
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When user click on button i show new view controller with Sprite Kit scene. But when game is over i go back to menu. And if we click **Start game** again, fps falls from 60(in my case) to 30, then if again to 20 etc. Seems like old view controller still working. How to dismiss it ?

I read similar questions, but didn't find answer in them.

Comment: Show us the code corresponding to game over event

Comment: @alexburtnik same function but to main menu

Comment: Unless you provide more details about how you dismiss your controller I can't help you. "same function but to main menu" it is not what I asked. Please provide your code.

Comment: @alexburtnik `if lifes == 0 {
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainMenuViewController") as? MainMenuViewController {
            vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now your issue is clear.

You should not present a new `MainViewController` when game is over. This will lead you to potentially infinite stack of view controllers like this:
Main -> Game -> Main -> Game -> ...
Instead you should dismiss your Game vc and return to the previous controller, so that you will always have one or two controllers in memory.

So you should replace this:

```
if lifes == 0 {
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainMenuViewController") as? MainMenuViewController {
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

With this:

```
if lifes == 0 {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //will bring you to previous Main vc
}
```

**Edit:**

If you have more than two controllers to show, you should consider navigation controller approach. Basically you create it with rootViewController (MainVC), then push GameVC, then push GameOver.

In MainVC:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameVC, animated: true)
```

In GameVC:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameOverVC, animated: true)
```

To pop only only one controller:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

To pop to the first controller:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: but if i will have a few controllers like: Menu->Game->GameOver->Menu ? How remove Game View controller after finish ?

Comment: @Arti: You should better use navigation stack for this purpose. Have a look at the updated answer.